# Regarding argument to a then function in protractor. In the below code what will be passed to 'value'?

Tags: javascript, protractor

If bar is equal to jsonObj.alias it should return true or false and that should be the argument to next then function right. But that's not happening here. plz clear this. what will be the argument to the last then function and how?

```
element
    .all(by.repeater('portGroup in displayedCollection'))

    .filter(function(eachRow) {
        return eachRow.element(by.css('td:nth-child(2)')).getText().then(function(bar){
            return bar === jsonObj.alias;
        });
    })

    .then(function(values){
        values[0].element(by.css('span[class="ng-binding"]')).click();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting your code into two parts enable you to understand your problem.

```
var satisfiedRows = element
    .all(by.repeater('portGroup in displayedCollection'))

    .filter(function(eachRow) {
        // the filter function is to find out from all rows 
        // which's 3rd cell text equal to `jsonObj.alias`
        return eachRow.element(by.css('td:nth-child(2)')).getText().then(function(bar){
            return bar === jsonObj.alias;
        });
    });  // we can split your code at here


    // satisfiedRows is a promise which eventual value are satisfied rows
    // you call `then()` on this promise, the argument `function()` will be 
    // passed-in the promise's eventual value. In your case, 
    // they are rows which's 3rd cell text equal to `jsonObj.alias`
    satisfiedRows.then(function(rowsAfterFilter){
        rowsAfterFilter[0].element(by.css('span[class="ng-binding"]')).click();
    });
```